# Limit of a function in two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem:

Find the limit as $(x,y)$ tends to $(2,2)$ for the following function:
$$f(x,y)= ⁡\frac{y^2-2xy+x^2}{x-y}.$$

Not sure what to do for this question, how would I go about solving?

Answer (score 2):

Start with $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$ to rewrite

$$f(x,y)={(x-y)^2\over x-y}=x-y$$

And the limit is now obviously $0$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 2,2 \right)  }{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-2xy+{ { y }^{ 2 } } }{ x-y } = } \lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 2,2 \right)  }{ \frac { \left( x-y \right) ^{ 2 } }{ x-y } =\lim _{ \left( x,y \right) \rightarrow \left( 2,2 \right)  }{ x-y=0 }  } $$

Comment: The limit is $0$ because the function is $x-y$ and not $x+y$. You are confusing $x^2-y^2$ and $(x-y)^2$

Comment: thanks @marwalix i missed it